# Android ListView: Do Not Show TextView When Null

Tags: java, android, listview, textview

I've got a ListView that displays an array that is generated dynamically by the user from within the activity. Basically, the program is a timer and the user can choose a time they would like an alarm to go off and also provide a description of what they should be doing when that alarm goes off.

I have the ListView setup using a SimpleAdapter which calls a alarm_list_item.xml, which contains two TextView's and an icon that I want displayed for each item in the list.

```
adapter = new AlarmListAdapter(this, stringArray, R.layout.alarm_list_item, new String[] {"name", "alert"}, new int[] {R.id.ListViewItem, R.id.ListViewItemSub});
```

When the user chooses not to add a custom dialog for the alarm I would like to set the visibility of the TextView in alarm_list_item.xml to GONE so it doesn't show as a blank space on the list. When I try to set this parameter from within the activity I get a NullPointerException because I am assuming that the xml file isn't actually an object but more or less just used as a reference for the ListView. Is there a way to accomplish this?

So far I am getting around the problem by setting the text to "No Custom Notification Set" but i'd like a cleaner option and just remove the line all together when its not in use.

alarm_list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/alarm_icon"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">
</ImageView>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ListViewItem"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textSize="16sp">
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ListViewItemSub"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textSize="10sp">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Snippet of the activity where the ListView resides:

```
        stringArray = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.AlarmListView);
    adapter = new AlarmListAdapter(this, stringArray, R.layout.alarm_list_item, new String[] {"name", "alert"}, new int[] {R.id.ListViewItem, R.id.ListViewItemSub});
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    registerForContextMenu(list);

}

private void updateListArray(){
    stringArray.clear();
    if(!arrayList.isEmpty()){
    for(int i=0; i<arrayList.size(); i++){

        String name = arrayList.get(i).getName();
        String alert = arrayList.get(i).getAlertDialog();

        if(alert == ""){
            alert = "No Custom Notification Set";
        }

        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("name", name);
        map.put("alert", alert);
        stringArray.add(map);
    }
    }
}
```

Adapter Code:

```
    public AlarmListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list, int textViewResourceId, String[] fields, int[] textViewId) {
    super(context, list, textViewResourceId, fields, textViewId);
    this.list = list;
    this.context = context;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

View v = convertView;
if (v == null) {
    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.alarm_list_item, null);
    Log.i("getView = ", "" + v);
    Log.i("list alert = ", "" + list.get(position).get("alert"));
}


if(list.get(position).get("alert") == null){    
    v.findViewById(R.id.ListViewItemSub).setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

}

public void forceReload(){
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

LogCat Error:

```
07-11 12:16:23.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(190): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
07-11 12:16:23.573: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(190): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-11 12:16:23.573: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(190):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1275)
07-11 12:16:23.573: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(190):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1147)
07-11 12:16:23.573: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(190):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1060)
07-11 12:16:23.573: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(190):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7703)
07-11 12:16:23.573: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(190):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:2989)
07-11 12:16:23.573: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(190):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:888)
07-11 12:16:23.573: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(190):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:619)
07-11 12:16:23.573: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(190):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:280)
07-11 12:16:23.573: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(190):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7703)
07-11 12:16:23.573: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(190):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:2989)
07-11 12:16:23.573: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(190):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:888)
07-11 12:16:23.573: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(190):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:350)
07-11 12:16:23.573: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(190):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:278)
07-11 12:16:23.573: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(190):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7703)
07-11 12:16:23.573: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(190):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:2989)
07-11 12:16:23.573: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(190):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:888)
07-11 12:16:23.573: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(190):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:350)
07-11 12:16:23.573: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(190):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:278)
07-11 12:16:23.573: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(190):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7703)
07-11 12:16:23.573: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(190):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:2989)
07-11 12:16:23.573: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(190):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
07-11 12:16:23.573: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(190):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7703)
07-11 12:16:23.573: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(190):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:464)
07-11 12:16:23.573: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(190):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:278)
07-11 12:16:23.573: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(190):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7703)
07-11 12:16:23.573: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(190):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:2989)
07-11 12:16:23.573: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(190):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
07-11 12:16:23.573: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(190):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7703)
07-11 12:16:23.573: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(190):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:747)
07-11 12:16:23.573: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(190):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1613)
07-11 12:16:23.573: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(190):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-11 12:16:23.573: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(190):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-11 12:16:23.573: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(190):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
07-11 12:16:23.573: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(190):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-11 12:16:23.573: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(190):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-11 12:16:23.573: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(190):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
07-11 12:16:23.573: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(190):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
07-11 12:16:23.573: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(190):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.

SimpleAdapter getView Override Code:

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

View v = convertView;
if (v == null) {
    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.alarm_list_item, null);
}


if(list.get(position).get("alert") == null){    
    v.findViewById(R.id.ListViewItemSub).setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

}
```

The problem was with the return statement. I needed to return the super values.

Comment: Due the reuse of the cells, you'll need to put an `else` clause to let it being visible again.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to over ride the Adapter's [bindView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#bindView%28android.view.View,%20android.content.Context,%20android.database.Cursor%29) or [getView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) methods: in there you'll be able to set the visibility on the desired View. [This](http://androidgroup.blogspot.com/2011/07/android-developers-modify-listview-item.html) is a poorly-formatted (but technically correct) example.

EDIT: try something like this:

```
@Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                        if(list.get(position).get("alert") == ""){      
        v.findViewById(R.id.ListViewItem).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        v.findViewById(R.id.ListViewItemSub).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
return convertView;

}
```

Comment: So after overriding the getView in the adapater should I use a for loop to iterate through the ArrayList populating the ListView and check if the value is null? If it is null do I need to inflate the view in order to edit the visibility setting? The adapter extends the SimpleAdapter so I can't seem to be able to reference the TextView with findViewById.

Comment: `getView` will be called once for each item in the Adapter. For each call you'll be passed the current View and the position: inflate the view from the XML if the View you were passed is null and then adjust the visibility if you need to.

Comment: I updated my question to include the adapter code. I am getting a nullpointerexception each time I try to run this. Does the getView actually run through each item in the array that was passed into the adapter?

Comment: If you continue to get an exception modify your question to include the logcat output: makes it much easier to figure out specifically what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

View v = convertView;
if (v == null) {
LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.alarm_list_item, null);
}


if(list.get(position).get("alert") == ""){    
    v.findViewById(R.id.ListViewItemSub).setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

return convertView;

}
```

Comment: Getting the same logCat error with this code. The error is revolving around being able to obtain the view, but I can't figure out why it can't see the view. I am running this in the adapter class and not within the activity associated with the adapter. Is that an issue?

Comment: Hmm I don't really know what is causing it now